# Could not find org.nodejs:node

Tags: node.js, gradle

I am trying to build my gui application (angular implementation) and I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find 
org.nodejs:node:10.14.1.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.14.1/ivy.xml
```

build.gradle contains (relevant to nodejs):

```
node {
version = '10.14.1'
npmVersion = '6.4.1'
download = false
}

dependencies {
    classpath("com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:1.2.0")
 }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.moowork.node'
```

gradle.properties contains:

```
systemProp.https.proxyUser=''
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=''
systemProp.http.proxyUser=''
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=''
systemProp.https.proxyHost=internet.proxy.company.com
systemProp.https.proxyPort=port
systemProp.http.proxyHost=internet.proxy.company.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=port
```

npm config contains:

```
https-proxy=http://internet.proxy.company.com:port/
proxy=http://internet.proxy.company.com:port/
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
sslVerify=false
strict-ssl=false
```

Even if I remove the node js dependency (for giggles), it still throws this error. Any help is greatly appreciated. At first, I thought it was a proxy issue but I do not think that is the case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`com.moowork.node` is not actively maintained and has this issue. Switch to the fork of this plugin which is actively maintained and has fixed this issue.

https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin/

For more details as to why it is failing, see [this](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/pull/349#issuecomment-540650222) comment.